# Keep service in sync with 2 controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

Our app has a service **campaign** that is used in our main product controller, after being resolved by the router.

MainCtrl:

```
$scope.campaign = campaign;
$scope.campaign.someProp = dynamicPerProduct();
```

Line 2^ adds a property that is campaign specific, like overriding the default phone number.

I was under the assumption that this would bind to the original service object by reference, but *adding or changing a property via the $scope in MainCtrl does not seem to pass to the InterimCtrl controller, which reloads the original data from the campaign service*.

Activating the interim page is as simple as adding /interim to the end of a product page. Is it because I re-resolve the campaign service in the router that the service does not share scope across both controllers?

The interim controller:

```
 $scope.campaign = campaign;
 // causes refresh of data, does not pick up on line 2 from above example
```

Router:

```js
$routeProvider
  .when('/:groupName/:productName/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    resolve: {
      campaign: ['$route', 'campaign',
        function($route, campaign) {
          return campaign.getCampaign($route.current.params.groupName, $route.current.params.productName)
            .then(function(campaignResult) {
              return campaignResult;
            });
        }
      ]
    }
  }).when('/:groupName/:productName/interim', {
    templateUrl: 'views/interim.html',
    controller: 'InterimCtrl',
    resolve: {
      campaign: ['$route', 'campaign',
        function($route, campaign) {
          return campaign.getCampaign($route.current.params.groupName, $route.current.params.productName)
            .then(function(campaignResult) {
              return campaignResult;
            });
        }
      ]
    }
  })
```

Service:

```js
angular.module('campaign', [])
  .factory('campaign', function($log, $http, $q, $rootScope) {

    var campaigns = {};

    var getCampaign = function(groupName, productName, shortName) {

      var apiEndPoint; //defined by env, not necessary for example

      var campaign = campaigns[shortName];
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      if (campaign) {
        deferred.resolve(campaign);
      }

      $http.get(apiEndPoint, { cache: true }).then(function(response) {

        if (angular.isObject(response.data)) {
          campaigns[response.data.shortName] = {};
          angular.copy(response.data, campaigns[response.data.shortName])
          deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }
      })
      return deferred.promise;
    };

  
    return {
      getCampaign: getCampaign
    };

  });
```